# Using/storing derived member in derived class with base class that stores base member

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, smart-pointers, raii

A situation I often come up against is having a set of classes, `Base` and `Derived`, where the `Base` class has ownership of a base-class member `BaseMember`, and the `Derived` class has a reference or pointer to the same object, but as a `DerivedMember`.

For example, a UI panel class that contains a specific instance of a certain type of control with some special-control functions, inheriting from a general class that contains a general control and has general-control functions.

First, say that `BaseMember` is inherited by `DerivedMemeber`.

Without using smart pointers, I might do something like this:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    // receive ownership but only because we say so,
    // someone else can still try to delete as it's "just a pointer"
    Base(BaseMember* _bmember):
        bmember(_bmember)
    {}

public:
    virtual ~Base()
    {
        // perform an owner's duty
        delete bmember;
    }

    // functions that might be based on BaseMember + other base state
    void SetMemberId(....) 
    {
        bmember->SetId(baz);
    }

private:
    int baz;
    BaseMember* bmember; //owned, but not smartly
}

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    Derived(DerivedMember* _dmember):
        Base(_dmember),
        dmember(_dmember)
    {}

    // functions that only make sense for Derived + Derived/Base state
    void SetDerivedFrobulation()
    {
        // only a DerivedMember has frobulation, so only
        // Derived allows users to access it
        dmember->setFrobulation(foo);
    }

private:
    int foo; // some state
    DerivedMember* dmember; // no ownership here
}
```

With smart pointers (C++11 and up, specifically, I don't really care about older C++ in this case), I am tempted to do something like this and never let the `Base/DerivedMember` object out into dumb-pointer-land where it could leak if there was an exception somewhere inconvenient.

```
class Base
{
protected:
    // receive ownership
    Base(std::unique_ptr<BaseMember> _member):
        member(std::move(_member))
    {}

    virtual ~Base()
    {}

public:
    // public access functions here as before

private:
    std::unique_ptr<BaseMember> member;
}

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    // pass the ownership down by unique_ptr
    Derived(std::unique_ptr<DerivedMember> _dmember):
        Base(std::move(_dmember)),
        dmember(_dmember.get()) // _dmember is moved! SEGFAULT if access dmember later!
    {}

    // public access functions here as before

private:
    // handy handle to the derived class so we don't need to downcast the base (or even access it!)
    DerivedClass* dmember
}
```

As I noted there, you can't "steal a peek" at the `DerivedMember` class as it comes in to the `Derived` constructor, because the `unique_ptr` is `move`d away before `Derived` gets a look in.

I can see a solution in providing a `protected` access to the `BaseMember` and `static_cast`ing back to `DerivedMember` in the `Derived` constructor (i.e. after the `Base` constructor is done), but this seems an ugly way to get access back to a variable we let slip though our fingers!

Another way could be each inheritor of `Base` owns the pointer, and base just gets a dumb pointer. In this case, the `Base` destructor doesn't get access to the member, as it's already gone. Also it would duplicate the ownership logic needlessly.

I think either:

- This is symptomatic of an anti-pattern and the design of the whole `Base`/`Derived`/`BaseMember`/`DerivedMember` system is not good practice.
- I'm missing a trick and there is a clean way to do this without fumbling a smart pointer and making a leak possible or adding functions and exposing interfaces or casting too much.

Is this a good pattern for re-use, or should I look elsewhere?

### Expanding on the use case (EDIT)

In a core library, I have a class `DataInterpreter` which shows "some interpretation" of data - could be a string, an image, etc. This is then inherited by, amongst others, `TextInterpreter` which presents a `string`.

I then have a `DataDisplayPanel` class which represents a piece of UI for displaying in an abstract sense. Exactly what is in this panel will depend on the interpreter used: a `TextInterpreter` should get a text entry field and say a button to set some text display option, and that is handled in `TextDisplayPanel`, which has "special" knowledge of the text aspect of the interpreter.

There is then a `DataAggregatePanel` which combines a number of `DataDisplayPanels` and provides some global settings that affect all displays (via virtual functions), and manages the panels in a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataDisplayPanel> >`. This aggregate class doesn't deal with any of the derived classes at all, any functions would be polymorphic and defined in the base.

In the application (which depends on the core library), these classes are extended (by inheritance or composition, whichever makes more sense). For example, if the application is a WX GUI, I might have `wxDataAggregatePanel` which contains `wxTextDisplayPanel` (and others), all of which are `wxPanels`. In this case, `wxTextDisplayPanel` might own a `wxTextEntry` and either own or inherit `TextInterpreter` and use its knowledge of the `TextInterpreter`'s specific methods to fill the text box with a string.

Comment: Upvoted for interest. I've run into this (anti-?)pattern in the past, though thankfully recent (and seemingly infinite) rewrites of this project have made the whole architecture exponentially less code-smelly and meant I don't need to think about it right now... but I'm still interested in answers to the questions I had in the past. I also just realised this all seems highly relevant to the PImpl idiom and inheritance among implementation classes.

Comment: I'd see this as an anti pattern. Feels like you're associating stuff that isn't meant to be associated like that. Can you possibly extend the use case(s) a bit more?

Comment: In your first sample you waste memory by storing two pointers to the same object. If you need `Base` be a truly polymorphic, you might have private `virtual BaseMember *getMember() = 0` there and store `DerivedMember*` in `Derived` object only. If `Base` only serves as a common implementation for other classes, you might make it a template (see CRTP) and store `DerivedMember*` in the `Base<DerivedMember>` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use delegating constructor:

```
class Derived: public Base
{
public:

    Derived(std::unique_ptr<DerivedMember> _dmember):
        Derived(_dmember, _dmember.get())
    {}

    // public access functions here as before
private:
 Derived(std::unique_ptr<DerivedMember>& _dmember, DerivedMember* ptr):
        Base(std::move(_dmember)),
        dmember(ptr)
    {}
private:
    // handy handle to the derived class so we don't need to downcast the base (or even access it!)
    DerivedClass* dmember
};
```

Comment: Cool, now it's the excellent answer I always suspected it was :D

Comment: This is a good way to get access to the pointer, and a useful technique in general to get access to a `unique_ptr` before turning it over to a base class. On the other hand, it needs repeating for each derived class, and I still can't shake the feeling that the whole hierarchy is flawed!

Comment: You may add a layer `template <typename DerivedClassT> class DerivedT` and then have all `Derived` inherit from `DerivedT<DerivedClass>` (which has so the only tricky constructor).